# Powershell CSV Export - Change columns

Tags: powershell

I want the different results of the patterns in different rows but exactly in that order. My Problem is, it's all in 1 column.

```
$path = ".\WSUS_Report.txt"

$pattern_rubrik = '(?<=Kind).+?($)'
$pattern_result = '(?<=Result).+?(?=\.)'
$pattern_sysname = '(?<=System).+?($)'

$content = Select-String -Path $Path -Pattern $pattern_sysname,$pattern_rubrik,$pattern_result -AllMatches

$content | Out-GridView
$content | Select-Object -Property Line  |  Export-Csv Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Example:

It's currently this:

[image]

I want it like this:
[image]

But I have no idea what to do

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide a few sanitized rows of your wsus report.txt file so we can help work through a solution with you?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AcbM8zuv

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the output of this report.  How could I generate one for myself?  I think the redaction was so thorough that I just can't make sense of it 

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring $content as a collection before putting stuff in it.

```
$content = @()
```

then just | it to out-csv; no need to select-object -property line